# Definition of $G$-subspace

Tags: representation-theory

I've came across the term $G$-subspace in "The Local Langlands for GL(2)". Does it mean the same as $G$-stable subspace? One instance of the phrase is

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a smooth representation of $G$; then any $G$-stable subspace of
$V$ provides a further smooth representation of $G$. Likewise, if $U$ is a $G$-subspace
of $V$, the natural representation of $G$ on the quotient $V/U$ is smooth.

Comment: If you interpret "$G$-subspace" as "$G$-stable subspace", then, at least the quoted sentence is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean the same as $G$-stable subspace.